# WebSocket servers and firewall

Tags: proxy, websocket, firewall, redirect

I have two WebSocket servers both running on different ports than 80 and 443. These two servers are running behind a firewall which only has port 80 and 443 open.

```
WebSocket Server A:800 |
                       |-----|FireWall:80 & 443|-----> INTERNET
WebSocket Server B:801 |
```

What I am looking for is a way for my clients to get connected to the WebSocket servers without knowing their port and without me opening the firewall for any other ports rather than 80 and 443.

So I was thinking maybe an intermediary server (or proxy server) between my firewall and WebSocket servers can be configured in a fashion that when clients asks for `www.mywebsite.com/a` on port 80 or 443 (to pass the firewall) the intermediary server connects the client to WebSocket Server A. And when client asks for `www.mywebsite.com/b` on port 80 or 443 the intermediary server connects him to WebSocket Server B. Is this possible? and if so, is there any server you may know of that has this feature implemented?

On a different note (maybe not very different), what would be the differences between [TCP hole punch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) and the approach I explained above?

Comment: Well its definitely possible if you control everything after the firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "WebSockets reverse proxy". You will need another logical or physical node between your firewall and your WebSocket servers. You might be running all three nodes on the same system which is why I mention "logical".

This space is rapidly changing and solutions are fairly immature. Probably the best option for your case is using [HAProxy for WebSocket reverse proxy](http://blog.silverbucket.net/post/31927044856/3-ways-to-configure-haproxy-for-websockets). Search for "WebSocket reverse proxy" for more information. [This article](http://www.exratione.com/2012/07/proxying-websocket-traffic-for-nodejs-the-present-state-of-play/) is a bit old but should give you a reasonable overview of options.

**Update**: looks like WebSocket proxy support just landed in Nginx yesterday: [press release](http://nginx.com/news/nginx-websockets.html), [commit with example](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/5073/nginx)

Comment: @kanaka, What about Kaazing? Do they have  a websocket reverse proxy?

Comment: @Pacerier not sure (haven't looked at them in a while). But if you find out, please post back here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to configure HAProxy to redirect my request based on the URI thanks to the [link](http://blog.silverbucket.net/post/31927044856/3-ways-to-configure-haproxy-for-websockets) @kanaka provided in his answer. So this is what I've done:

Once you `make` HAProxy you can find haproxy under `usr/local/sbin`. The script runs with `-f` flag for the configuration file. Look into `/etc/` and in case you do not have any `haproxy.cfg` simply `mkdir -p /etc/haproxy` and then `vi /etc/haproxy.cfg` and paste your configuration. The configuration file for version 1.5 is described [here](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#2.1) with all the parameters one can use in it. This is how my `haproxy.cfg` file looks like:

```
global
    log  127.0.0.1 local0
    log  127.0.0.1  local1 notice
    maxconn  4096
    uid  99
    gid  99
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode  http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries  3
    option  redispatch
    option  http-server-close
    maxconn  2000
    contimeout  5000
    clitimeout  50000
    srvtimeout  50000

frontend public
    bind *:80
    acl is_websocket1 path_beg -i /a # if the path starts with /a
    acl is_websocket2 path_beg -i /b # if the path starts with /b
    use_backend ws1 if is_websocket1
    use_backend ws2 if is_websocket2
    default_backend www

backend www
    timeout server 30s
    server www1 127.0.0.1:8001 # the port we have our webserver running on

backend ws1
    timeout server 600s
    server ws1 127.0.0.1:800 # the port we have our websocket server 1 running on

backend ws2
    timeout server 600s
    server ws2 127.0.0.1:801 # the port we have our websocket server 2 running on
```